# Is it possible to receive explicit intent from different app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working with a bluetooth button and Zebra TC20. I want to start zebra's scan when extra bluetooth button get clicked.

Bluetooth button is supported by their app - flic. There is an option to send Intent. So I would like to send intent to my app. This could be done by implicit intent. But I am building this app so I know exact activity when the scan should be triggered.

From what I read I should use explicit intent if I want the activity which I know the name, but everywhere explicit intent is tied within one app.

Is it possible to call specific activity of my app from another app?

This question is edited.

Comment: *after edit was made* You can look at [this tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-start-another-activity-of-another-application/) your app will be the second app in the tutorial, you have to set an intent-filter in your manifest. In your button config app, if you can do that, you have to set the intent action name of the activity you want to launch

Comment: This tutorial is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, can you post it as an answer so I'll accept it?

Comment: i edited my original answer so you can have both ideas, you might want to use the broadcast system too if it is available with the bluetooth button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/mobile-computers/tc20-android-v7.1.2-ig-en.pdf) at page 52-61 everything is explained, i had to implement it with a ET55, but it seems to be the same process.

I personnaly did it using the Intent output option ith intent delivered via broadcast.

First you can make open the DataWedge App (the app should be preinstalled, it is where you configure things about the scanner)

1. You create a profile for your app
2. You click on the profile and you check the `Profile enabled option`
3. You enable barcode input and Intent ouput, disable Keystroke and ip output
4. You associate your app (`Associated apps` option)
5. (go to Page 75-76 of manual) You set the intent action with something like `datawedge.yourapp.SCANNER_RESULT`
6. You left category blank
7. You set intent delivery to `Broadcast Intent`
8. For the rest the default option should be ok

Then, in your app you have to register the broadcast receiver (in `onCreate()`):

```
//first you implement the action to be executed when it receives the broadcast
receiverZebra = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String scanResult = intent.getStringExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.data_string");
        /*
            do things with the barcode here
        */
    }
};

//then make a filter for the broadcast
filterZebra = new IntentFilter();
filterZebra.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
//the action you set in step 5 in datawedge
filterZebra.addAction("datawedge.yourapp.SCANNER_RESULT");
```

Then in the `onStart` and `onStop` methods you can register/unregister your broadcast receiver

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    registerReceiver(receiverZebra, filterZebra);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(receiverZebra);
}
```

There are other ways to implement it, there wouldn't be other option than Intent output if there were not but it works great for me. I don't think there is much differences between the TC20 and ET55 so it should work for you as well

### After the question was edited

> Taken from [this tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-start-another-activity-of-another-application/)

In the configuration app of your button, you should be able to link an intent action name to the bluetooth button. To receive it, you have to set an intent filter in your app manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myapplication.activitytolaunch"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.myapplication.ACTIVITY_TO_LAUNCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And your button will have to launch the intent : `"com.example.myapplication.ACTIVITY_TO_LAUNCH"`

If you want to launch the activity directly, you can use the second part of the answer. If you have to process the barcodes when your app is opened (i.e. adding the barcodes to a list), if you can tell the button to broadcast an intent, you can use the first part.

Comment: I'll try your advice once I have the Zebra TC20 in my hand, but the question I asked is about bluetooth button and possibility of explicit intent from different source, than opened app. When somebody press this button I want to call specific activity in an open app and show Toast for example.

Comment: Isn't the scanner (and scan button) built-in ? I don't think it use Bluetooth. If it does it is about the same process, you just have to connect it before you use it and then datawedge does the job. The part in datawedge where I say you choose `brodcast intent`, you can choose `start activity` (I think that's the name or something similar) that directly start a given activity. To get the barcode you have to get extras of the sent intent with the same key name as in the broadcast receiver I gave you

Comment: There are build in buttons but we have bought extra bluetooth button. Now when we mount the scanner on hand and the button on palm we can accomplish hands free scanner. I'll try to edit the question to be more accurate.